# Permutation and combination with males/females

Tags: permutations

There are $6$ males and $6$ females in the finals of a talent competition. A contest is held to pick the top $3$ winners in both the male and female categories in order of merit. How many different entries must be completed to ensure a winning order?

Comment: Is this a sorting problem?